# What version of Hive is packed in CDH 5.5.x?

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh

I would like to know the version of Hive that comes along with the CDH 5.5.x version?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the answer. CDH 5.5.x comes with Hive 1.1.0. For more details of various other tools' version check out this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball_55.html).